# Error when trying to write a dataframe to Excel

Tags: r

New to R, new to stackoverflow.  I need to take the Caravan dataset from the ISLR package and export it into Excel.

Here is my code and my error:

```
library(xlsx)
write.xlsx(Caravan, "c:/Users/me/Desktop/PRACTICE/R/Caravan.xlsx")

Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Unsure how to troubleshoot this one - thoughts?  Thanks.

Comment: As described [here](http://www.bramschoenmakers.nl/en/node/726), before loading the xlsx package, run the following code to increase the amount of space allocated `options( java.parameters = "-Xmx4g" )`.

Comment: It worked - thanks for pointing me in the right direction.